# MS Access masquerade form variable value

Tags: ms-access, vba

**The Issue**

I have a pre-existing Report that I need to run that refers to the code

```
Forms!frm_report1_selection!ddlState
```

I am trying to access the report from the form *frm_report3* and as such the Report will not be able to find the record stated above.

I can rewrite the report, but, it has roughly 30 subreports that would all need to be copied and updated to find Forms!frm_report3_selection!ddlState

**The Question**

Is it possible to create an alias (or masquerading) variable to set the value of *forms!frm_report1_selection!ddlState* when posting from *frm_report3_selection*?

Comment: Try to create Get Property in Report1

Comment: Where is the field value referred to? Could you set a variable on report open which indicates what form opened it? Or could you open the form_report1 in the background at the same time? There's multiple ways of dealing with this, it just depends on your setup

Answer (score 0):

Set up a variable in your report and set it to the value of the form that is loaded when you open your report.

Use a function like this to see which form is open;

```
Function IsFormLoaded(strForm As String) As Boolean

Dim frm As Form
Dim bln As Boolean

For Each frm In Forms
    If frm.Name = strForm Then
        IsFormLoaded = True
    End If
Next

End Function
```

then set your variable depending on which is open when the report loads

```
Dim ddlState as String

If IsFormLoaded("frm_report1_selection") then
    ddlState = Forms!frm_report1_selection!ddlState
ElseIf IsFormLoaded("frm_report3_selection") then
    ddlState = Forms!frm_report3_selection!ddlState
End if
```

Then use the variable in the report.